# AC 250V 50Hz or 48V DC and reduce the input voltage down to 24V / 1W Output. How can I generate DC/DC converter clock signal

Tags: power-supply, power, power-electronics, dc-dc-converter, clock

I have to design a a power supply that can accept either 250V 50Hz AC or 48V DC from the same input terminals. Output has to be 5V/1W. Circuit cost has to be below 10 euros. It is meant to work either from the output of solar installation or the outlet. The diagram of the system I thought of implementing is below.

[image]

I have ran some spice simulations to see if it would work. The simulation circuit can be found below. All the parameters of the buck converter I calculated using texas insturments buck converter calculator: https://www.ti.com/tool/BUCK-CONVCALC. The output does not need to be regulated in my opinion as it will feed into a proper dc-dc converter anyway. it just needs to scale down the 320V peak to peak voltage down to a level that can be fed into a comercially available 3kV isolated dc-dc converter.

The main problem for me begins when I have to generate the clock signal for the discrete buck converter. According to my simulations the circuit I provided below works. The 100ohm load is to simulate the isolated dc-dc converted that I would put in the output. The GS voltage of the PMOS has to be below the threshold voltage when the mosfet is conducting and above the threshold when it is not conducting. How can I generate such a clock signal in this case?

[image]

Comment: I would use a USB charger to get from 250 down to 5V.  Then a DC to DC converter to get from 48 to 5V.  Connect the two 5V lines together.

Comment: You’d normally use a buck controller chip as you need more than just a clock source. At your power level, you could simply have a circuit that turns off when the instantaneous voltage exceeds a given value - basically it chops the top off the sinewave. A capacitor hopefully smooths it all out for your dc/dc converter. Note that for a commercial design there is EMC regs you’ll need to comply with. This might be the greater challenge.

Comment: @Kartman do you know which norms I would have to take into account other than IEC 60664-1?

Comment: There’s probably half a dozen you need.  find a similar device and see what it complies with. For a commercial application, I’d suggest you find someone with the required experience to guide you. There are many things to consider.

Comment: @Kartman thank you, i will consult a senior engineer for norms compliance. Your suggestion with a buck controller was very helpfull.